# why does the useEffect hook even with no dependecies still "run" on the client side even though the page has been pre-rendered by next-js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, hydration, pre-rendering

I thought that the pre-rendering process would mean that hooks like useEffect will already be executed on the server.

I read something about hydration, don't know if it explains this occurrence but couldn't understand it clearly from the blogs that explained the term.

Comment: `useEffect` never runs on the server. Even if your page is pre-rendered, whatever code you include in a `useEffect` hook will not be part of the server response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pre-rendering on the server side means the conversion of your react codes into a minimal HTML representation of your UI, it doesn't mean your component is mounting(i.e. elements are created and inserted into the DOM) or updating after initial mounting/rendering. Pre-rendering is specific to NextJS as in Server Side Rendering/Static Page Generation. `useEffect` runs at least once after the initial **render** and here render means either the mount or the update after the initial mount of the component whereas the server doesn't mount obviously and hence `useEffect` doesn't run on the server.

As for **hydration**, it is simply the process whereby the pre-rendered/static page is converted into a dynamic page when loaded by browser as it runs client side javascripts like attachment of event listeners for instance.